# Edge shows popup on submit

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I have an issue in Microsoft edge where when I click on:

```
<input type="submit" name="updateNobody" class="button arrow-right" value="Save">
```

It shows a popup saying:

"Resubmit form?
To refresh this page your browser needs to repeat any actions you've already taken. For example if you've already entered into a form your info will be resubmitted to the site"

This error only appear in MS Edge and not any of the other browsers.

Has anyone else experienced this error?

Comment: is the request going to a https?

Comment: Yes it is going to a https